# How to find a co-author?

Tags: publications, research-process, authorship

I am working on a manuscript and need some collaborations in the part which is out of my expertise. I personally don't know anyone in this field.

It will be a good paper to be published in a top journal. How can I find a co-author to help with this?

Is it OK if I send my manuscript to some academics in the field and invite them to collaborate, or it is an odd invitation?

Comment: what do your supervisor/advisor thinks of this?

Comment: It'll be odd if it comes from you.  Your adviser may have a better chance of establishing any collaboration.  I for example will not respond even if the email comes from a reputable uni or person.  The situation is no different to receiving a request from a stranger asking to help withdraw a supposedly multi-million dollar inheritance :)

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus, to be clear, are you saying that there is no way for a stranger to successfully start a collaboration with you over email?

Comment: @FábioDias where did this assumption come from that the OP has a supervisor?

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus I agree with Antonio Vargas. All collaborators were strangers one day. If email is not good to communicate with new people it's useless. Multi-million dollar emails are spam. If they were real, I would accept any email offer :D

Comment: @All Not so much assumption as bait, because advisor is the first step... you won't do real research, at this level, without one. Someone with the experience to be PI would not ask something like this (unlikely)

Comment: @ Then why mentioning "I" rather than "we"?

Comment: I suggest you using Reserchgate, whenever I need some collaboration or to use certain equipment I ask there, also I saw many of requests and questions about possible collaboration.

Comment: also many academics, postdocs, studnets would like to collaborate since you are offering coauthorship. I dont understand why some comments suggest different

Comment: @AntonioVargas yes.  Fundamentally, it is a trust issue.  There are ways to build trust: someone vouch for person X, my uni has an agreement that establishes some joint program.

Comment: Some useful advice here: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/68127/how-to-find-collaborators-for-a-research-projectpaper-or-a-series-of-papers

Comment: While it might be possible to find a collaborator via "cold" emails, I think the sort of things written in this question would be serious red flags for any potential collaborator. You know that it will be a strong paper that can be published in a top journal, yet you have not yet done all the research and in fact need help with something from outside your own field (which by definition you will have no idea how hard is). These things do not add up.

Answer (score 2):

A few possible things you may do for a prospective collaboration:

- Look for authors who published in the field which you wish to publish in (citing from [this post](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/68127/how-to-find-collaborators-for-a-research-projectpaper-or-a-series-of-papers)). You ought to have researched on a set of papers from which you would have developed your idea or an enhancement to. The authors from those papers may guide you.
- Contact in sites that facilitate collaboration and discussion like ResearchGate.net and Academia.edu. There are many who have collaborated this way and become from strangers to research associates.
- Mail invitation; this may or may not work. A discussed in the comments, your mail may be tossed by a spam filter or even be ignored. But it has worked before for some people.

Having stated above, getting *reliable* co-authors, may not be so easy. This is one of the reasons why professional research ought to be conducted with a supervisor/advisor or a mentor who is established in the field. They ought to guide you along these lines.